# Create war file with Windows batch and exclude specific directory without maven ant etc

Tags: batch-file, war

I've got some issues using Batch in windows trying to create a `.war` file and exclude certain directories from this file.

```
jar -cvf test.war .
```

This is a more basic way to create a `.war` file but i just can't find any way to properly filter the directory without having to whitelist each of them.

```
jar -cvf test.war images
```

This would only add the images dir to my file but it's not the way that i want to handle it.

I don't want to use something like **Ant** or **Maven**

Everything should be running from the **Windows command prompt** using Batch.

Thank you for any kind of reply and have a nice day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave up doing it like this, now im using a whitelist for files / directory to be added

Batch looking like:

```
set whitelist=
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (whitelist.txt) do set whitelist=!whitelist!%%a 
jar -cvf test.war %whitelist%
```

Whitelist looking like:

```
html
images
*.xml
```